# Print one (float) decimal using cout

Tags: c++, floating-point, iostream, css-position, cout

I have a float number and I want to print one digit after decimal. How can I do this using `cout`? I have tried the following code but its giving wrong display.

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    float time = 2.2;
    cout.precision(1);
    cout << time << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to set tge precision to one and float formatting flags to `fixed`:

```
std::cout << std::fixed << std::setprecision(1);
```

BTW, don't use `std::endl`. To get a newline use `'\n'` and if you really mean to flush the stream use `std::flush`.

Comment: Seems to require a link to [The little endl that couldn't](http://www.aristeia.com/Papers/C++ReportColumns/novdec95.pdf) (PDF) by Scott Meyers :)

Comment: Well, if I were to link an article I would, of course, link [this](http://kuhllib.com/2012/01/14/stop-excessive-use-of-stdendl/) one! I was genuinely unaware of Scott's article...

Comment: And I was genuinely unaware of yours :) Thanks for that link

Comment: @sehe: I should mention the `std::unitbuf` manipulator to Scott: this is how `std::cerr` gets unbuffered rather than using `setbuf(0, 0)`.

Comment: @DietmarKühl: Yep. And fixing the outdated info from Meyers' article: `unitbuf` is 0 by default on other streams, and `std::cout` is (permitted to be) buffered by default.

Comment: I just finished reading the article: Scott mentioned `unitbuf` and I can confirm: the default setting for `unitbuf` on streams is that it is **not** set (i.e., different from what Scott wrote in this somewhat aged article) according to Table 128 in 27.5.5.2 [basic.ios.cons] paragraph 3 (this is a reference to C++ 2011, though). Interestingly, Scott didn't mention `std::sync_with_stdio()` as a major performance hog... :)